# Zoom Cloud meetings is unusable because of an issue with display

Tags: display, themes, gui, cloud

I installed Zoom Cloud meetings but the application is unusable because of an issue with display.

It launches but then the interface is so transparent that one cannot read what's on the screen.

I tried various video modes, and versions of Zoom cloud meetings, including a 32-bit one, but no luck.

The laptop is an old HP running Ubuntu 19.10 and the video card is an AMD/ATI] RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: A new thing I just noticed: while waiting for the host to start a meeting, there is an option "Test Computer Audio". But I can't use it as it is 100% transparent. All I see are its window borders, despite having tried all the nome tweak appearance themes.  :(

Comment: You could try find a way to disable the trasparencies on your original there(Yaru) if it had them(i think that is the problem) or search a new desktop enviroment that are more suitable for you. Another option, but a bit messy, is change the desktop enviroment before use the program, and after that switch off to the original again. It could be easy archieved using log off option.

Comment: I will be trying that, as well as the other themes offered by gnome tweaks.

Thank you again!

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround!

I installed gnome tweaks and under Appearance, Themes, Applications, I changed from Yaru to Adwaita-dark and now the zoom client looks ok.

Now I would have to get used to a lot of dark looking applications, but at least I can I put that setting in when I need the app.

Comment: I always run in dark mode so that may explain why I haven't had an issue with it...

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a problem with wayland.
I'm using ubuntu22.10, and I change `ubuntu on wayland` for `ubuntu` when I log in.
Hope it helps.